# Which is more efficent PHP: array_intersect() OR array_intersect_key()

Tags: php

Is it more efficient to use the key intersect or the value intersect if both key and value have the same contents for example:

```
Array
(
    [743] => 743
    [744] => 744
    [745] => 745
    [746] => 746
    [747] => 747
    [748] => 748
)
```

Is there any difference in performance in using one or the other with the same values. Similar to the difference of using double or single quotes?

Comment: If it's just for a few dozen keys, it most likely won't matter - in that case pick what's nicest from a code readability perspective.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From another post: [I have two unordered integer arrays, and i need to know how many integers these arrays have in common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079158/i-have-two-unordered-integer-arrays-and-i-need-to-know-how-many-integers-these-a)

> Depending on your data (size) you
>   might want to use
>   array_intersect_key() instead of
>   array_intersect(). Apparently the
>   implementation of array_intersect
>   (testing php 5.3) does not use any
>   optimization/caching/whatsoever but
>   loops through the array and compares
>   the values one by one for each element
>   in array A. The hashtable lookup is
>   incredibly faster than that.